# Can I get full refund after the connecting flight gets cancelled in a booking trough a travel agency

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, connecting-flights, covid-19, refunds

I had made a booking to travel from London to Greece some days ago. There were two flights in the booking. The second flight got cancelled and I am looking for the travel agency to refund me for the whole trip as I cannot reach the second destination and there are no other alternatives due to coronavirus.

Note that the two flights were made in the same booking. I didn't pick them. The whole trip came up as an option. The two flights are operated by two different companies. The one that wasn't cancelled is operated by wizzair.

I am expecting the agency (kiwi.com) to fully compensate me. Is that possible? I know that in some cases, they might ask for the fees to the travel agency to be paid normally. Is that also correct?

Comment: Kiwi is known to actually sell separate flights on separate bookings and present them as a single booking. So the airlines are off the hook for any misconnections, etc, and Kiwi supposedly has a "Kiwi guarantee" to cover such issues. You need to look up the terms of that guarantee to see if and how you are covered in this situation.

Comment: @jcaron I will do that. I am still trying to read the terms. It is a book!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.